# How to make woocommerce single product gallery full width / boostrap compatible?

Tags: woocommerce

My product images are currently about 30% of the container column width... How to make this part:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
```

full 100% width?

Answer (score 0):

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4.images {
width: 100% !important;
max-width: 100%; float: none;
}

.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4.images img {
width: 100% !important;
max-width: 100%; float: none; 
}
```

This helped